# Fixing PATH on BASH / WINDOWS

Tags: bash, windows, path

I'm running Windows 10, and have BASH terminal in VisualStudioCode. My problem is that commands such as LS do not work. After some googling, i found that using this command fixes it:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

This however breaks some other stuff, and so, I copied output of `echo $PATH`, amalgamated the result with above-mentioned `export` command, and saved it into the file. Pasting resulting command into terminal fixes everything.

And I have to do that every single time I open new terminal, which is awkward.

Is there any way to add parts from the first `export` command to PATH? I know about "Edit the enviroment variable" option in windows, but either that does not work, or i'm doing it wrong, so telling me how to apply, eg. `/usr/bin` in there so that it works the same way as if I entered `export PATH=/usr/bin` into command line would help. Eventually, is there perhaps a way to autorun specific command each time new terminal is opened? That would help too.

Comment: Add the line to your `.bashrc`. Also, you can skip the `echo` part if you *extend* `PATH` instead of overwriting, like so: `PATH=$PATH:/new/stuff/goes/here:/more/new/stuff`

Comment: Ok that did work! I was confused, because upon launching terminal, i still see `bash: cut: command not found` - any idea where does that come from?

Comment: As commented, each shell has one or more configuration files (usually a .*conf or .*rc -- note that .*conf and .*conf are NOT typos of *.conf or *.rc; So for Bash, it is .bashrc, not bash.rc. Read the appropriate shell manual for why). _Also, and this is very significant, in Unix-like systems, **there is no such thing as a global/system environment**._ There are, however, several system-wide default shell configuration files in `/etc` (the shell documentaion will tell you which files and their names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Quoted from the question here as an answer:</sup>

Here's the fix that worked for me: create `C:\Users\username\.bashrc` file, and put the line you need to input manually into that line, it will run every time you launch `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Should you be having to alter your $PATH almost on a per application basis? I know that this practice is common in Windows. Since you have `/usr/local/bin` in your original $PATH:-

Try *never* changing your $PATH, so that applications may fail, due to multiple changes of $PATH.

Simply place symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` pointing to the true locations of your programs - which are placed in logical locations.